# Python csv reader not returning value when used with other operations

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to parse a csv file containing pincodes of Indian cities. I want a specific line from the file.

**When I try this, it works like charm:**

```
pinfile = open('pincodes.csv', 'r')

csv_file = csv.reader(pinfile)

for i, row in enumerate(csv_file):
    if i == 67208:
        x = " ".join(row)
        print(x)

pinfile.close()
```

Result:

> Padlya B.O 451220 B.O Delivery Khandwa Indore Madhya Pradesh Maheshwar West Nimar MADHYA PRADESH

**But when I add one line in between to calculate the number of rows in file, the for loop does not execute:**

```
pinfile = open('pincodes.csv', 'r')

totalrow = sum(1 for row in pinfile)  # To calculate number of rows

csv_file = csv.reader(pinfile)

for i, row in enumerate(csv_file):
    if i == 67208:
        x = " ".join(row)
        print(x)

pinfile.close()
```

No Result is displayed.

Please help. I searched whole forum but can't find anything similar to this.

Comment: Your totalrow calculation counts the number of lines in the file, which may be different from the number of rows returned by csv.reader. Rather than reading the file twice, read the rows into a list then use len() on the list.

Comment: The size of my csv file is more than 50MB, wouldn't it be memory inefficient to create list out of the csv.reader? Also I have confirmed the totalrow value by opening file with MS Excel it was correct.

Comment: Isn’t it time-iniefficient to read the file twice? I don’t know your constraints, up to you to make the choice but my preference is not to do things twice.. And on the counting rows: I don’t know what your data looks like so I’m suggesting something that would be safer in the general case where a cell might include a carriage-return. Don’t come complaining to me if sometime in the future your code inexplicably does somethng wrong. Code in general should be defensive, but you may choose to be less safe if you want. Good luck.

Comment: I didn't meant to offend you. I totally agree that reading the file twice is inefficient. But I was asking this question that if the size of file is of the order of ~100MB then would it freeze the script if i create a list object out of rows in the csv file? Also what If I use totalrow function on csv.reader, would it be any improvement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sum iteration reads to the end of the file, so there is nothing left for `csv` to read.  Reset the file to the beginning with `pinfile.seek(0)` before creating your reader.

Comment: Thanks this is the exact mistake i was doing. Thanks for saving my day.